# Are two languages regular if the union is regular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

Statement:

> For any two languages $L_1$ and $L_2$ if $L_1 \cup L_2$ is regular, then $L_1$ and $L_2$ are regular.

Why is this statement false? Could somebody give me an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$, $L_1 = \{ a^n b^n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $L_2 = \Sigma^* \setminus L_1$.

The union $L_1 \cup L_2$ is $\Sigma^*$ and hence is regular, but none of $L_1$ and $L_2$ is.

Comment: Why is $L_2$ not regular?

Comment: Because it is the complement of a non-regular language and regular languages are closed under complement. If $L_2$ was regular then so would be $\overline{L_2} = L_1$.

Comment: So if $L_2 = \Sigma^* \backslash L_1$ then $L_2 = \overline{L_1}$.

Comment: Yes. The definition of the complement $\overline{L}$ of a language $L$ is $\overline{L} = \Sigma^* \setminus L$.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not. Consider `L` to be non-regular, then L union its complement is the language of all words which is regular, but bot L and L complement are not.